# Using capybara to select radio button value that's in another field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I have a [multiple choice quiz game](https://vocab-matcher.herokuapp.com/quiz) written in Rails. I am trying to write an integration test that clicks through the quiz, selecting the correct answers. Here is my view:

```
<h2>The word is: <%= @question %> <br> </h2>
<h2>Your score is <%= session[:score] %> </h2>
<h2><%= @questions_remaining %> questions left!</h2>
    <% answers = @quiz_words.shuffle %>
      <%= form_tag("answer", method: "get") do %>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:answer, "#{answers.first.id}")%><%= answers.first.definition %><br>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:answer, "#{answers.second.id}")%><%= answers.second.definition %><br>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:answer, "#{answers.third.id}")%><%= answers.third.definition %><br>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:answer, "#{answers.fourth.id}")%><%= answers.fourth.definition %> <br>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :orig,  "#{@quiz_words.first.id}" %>
        <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
      <% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back to Index', root_path %> <br>
```

The correct answer is being generated in the html source as a hidden field id = 'orig' with the value as the answer.

I want Capybara to look for the hidden field and it's value ("13"), then in the next step, select the radio button that has the same value as the hidden field. Here is the html source that gets generated

[image]

I am new to Capybara and wasn't able to find if its possible looking through it's docs.

- Is this possible, if so can someone show me how to do it or point me to the docs for this?
- Is this the best way to test the quiz functionality? or would I be better testing it in another way? (unit tests?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, and you likely want to use an integration test here.

1. [Find](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) the hidden input
2. Get it's [value](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#value-instance_method)
3. [Choose](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions:choose) the radio with the value returned in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

The only slightly complicated thing here is that you want to look for a non-visible element, which you can do with the `visible: false` option.

```
orig_value = find('#orig', visible: false).value
choose(option: orig_value)
```